# EOF when reading a line

Tags: python

This is error is point towards this line of code:

```
s = str(input("Enter the String to be reversed:"))
```

---

```
def print_backward(string):
    if len(string) == 0:
        return string
    else:
        return print_backward(string[1:]) + string[0]

s = str(input("Enter the String to be reversed:"))
print(print_backward(s))
```

Comment: The return value of input function is of type `str`, by default. Specify the python version you are using.

Comment: Are u using python 2.x or 3.x

Comment: To help people diagnose this problem, perhaps you could include a copy of your terminal input/output?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work perfectly. Maybe include something like this to make input work on Python 2 and 3.

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```